# Angularjs make invisible accordion if subelement are filtered

Tags: angularjs, filter, accordion, visibility, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have created an accordion dynamically with angular.

Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" ng-model="searchSingoloCampo.title">

<accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories">

    <li ng-repeat="resource in category.resources | filter:searchSingoloCampo">

    </li>
</accordion-group>
```

The accordions is generated by a list , and inside each accordion there is a sublist of elements.
I can filter the element inside the accordion by using the simple angular filter, but i'm not able to handle the visibility of the Primary accordion when the sublist of element is completely "filtered" by the filter.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the solution!

Here how i have handled it:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-show="(category.resources | filter:searchSingoloCampo).length>0">
```

In this way, i handle the visibility of the "master" accordion when the subset of element are filtered!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to introduce another variable which stores the contents of the filtered array. When the size of this array is 0, you can close the accordion. Something along these lines:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories" close-accodrion="filteredResources.length">
    <li ng-repeat="resource in filteredResources = (category.resources | filter:searchSingoloCampo)">
    </li>
</accordion-group>
```

I made up the "close-accordion" attribute, not sure how you actually close your `accordion-group`. This assumes you can open/close it w/a boolean expression like `filteredResources.length`. Maybe you just want to hide it w/a `ng-show` or `ng-hide` ... the same approach would work.